# In Template, can I make a trigger change Path.Fill when Path is a ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf, templates, contentpresenter

I have a button template, where ContentPresenter is actually a Path.

On MouseOver, I want to change the Path.Fill.

See the template:

```
    <Style x:Key="spinButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#666666"/>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="#999999"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the code that uses this template:

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource spinButtonStyle}">
    <Path blah blah blah/>
</RepeatButton>
```

Now, in this case, that ContentPresenter is a Path.  Is there any way to change the Path.Fill color in the XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do now is bind the Path Fill property to your RepeatButton Foreground property:

```
Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RepeatButton}}}"
```

Comment: I ended up refactoring so it could be two different styles, but I think your solution would have worked just as well.  Wish I'd seen it sooner.  Thanks!